# Heroku deploying error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, heroku, out-of-memory

I want to deploy this: [blynk-server](https://github.com/Peterkn2001/blynk-server). But i have the error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
-----> Executing Maven
   $ mvn --update-snapshots -DskipTests=true clean package
   Error occurred during initialization of VM
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.<clinit>(Reference.java:232)
   
!     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
   We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
   please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
!     Push failed
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Dynos have a limited amount of memory (512 MB for Free Dynos) therefore you need to understand the memory requirements of your project.

Typically for Java projects you can:

1. remove from the Maven POM file unnecessary dependencies (analysing also transitive dependencies which could be left out)
2. configure libraries to load less data at startup (if possible)

The best next step is to analyse the memory footprint on your local dev environment to understand how much memory it requires and how far you are from the 512MB limit imposed by Heroku.